# Resources To Build a Framework

Tags: resources, frameworks

I'm thinking in create a framework, a little project with my friends, just to loose some time trying to build something, but we don't know where and how to start, then we are needing to know two things:

- Which languages is possible to do this?
- Where we can found some resources to begin(tutorials, sources...)?

All types of help are very welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use any language (that provides a mechanism for creating libraries) to build a framework.
- Learn the language and development platform of choice, first.  Creating a framework is just creating a library that provides a useful foundation for people.

Just trying to "Set out to build a framework" is probably not going to be too successful, however.  Typically, a successful project, especially one being done for fun, is one that fills some need... Think about what you are developing, or what you want to develop.  Create a project that is exciting, fun, and useful for you.

If, in the process, your project gets large, you can always pull out the building blocks and turn it into a framework for other people to use, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a framework in just about any language in existence, with a few common sense exceptions (such as a web server in Javascript).  The most important thing to remember is that in order to make code reusable, you have to first make it usable.  Your framework really has to make something simpler than doing it the original way.

Just curious, what kind of framework are you thinking about making?

Comment: I'm thinking to make a framework for internet things, like email, download, upload and file i/o too.

Comment: Cool.  If you haven't taken a look at it before, you might want to check out Spring.NET (the C# version of Java's Spring).  It is a framework that offers a ton of different functionality, including such things as dependency injection, database helpers, a web framework and all sorts of other cool stuff.  Might give you an idea of some pieces/parts that you want to try to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know where to start, what to do or how to do it, why not join an open source project of your liking? It'll be a great starting point. You'll have the chance to observe how to design frameworks, what are the challenges, practices for writing code, and answer a lot of other questions along the way.

Then, when you'll have a concrete idea about building something, you'll already have a lot of useful knowledge on how to make it successful.